# How can this text changer be started and stopped?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a solution to `stop` this textchanger, to `restart` and `reset`. Parts of it work, but with the `start` and the `reset` I still have problems. The whole thing is used for subtitles. Maybe there is a better solution for it. Can someone help me? Many Thanks.

```js
var texter = new Array
texter[0]='good day';
texter[1]='How can I be stopped and started ?';
texter[2]='';
texter[3]='everything should start again from the beginning with the reset button.';
texter[4]='that would be great !!!';
texter[5]='Many thanks for the help';
texter[6]='';
texter[7]='Ciao';
var i=0;

function changer(){
  document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML=texter[i];
  i++;
  if (i>7) i=0;
    window.setTimeout("changer()", 2500);
}

var info = document.getElementById("transbox");
    info.style.display = "none"; 
 
// Infobox display
function buttonShow() {  
    info.style.display = "";
}
// Infobox hidden
function buttonHide() {  
    info.style.display = "none";
}
function buttonStop() {  
    changer = stop;
}
function buttonSrart() {  
    window.setInterval ( "changer()", 2500 ); 
}
function buttonClear() { 
    changer(i=0); 
}
```

```css
#transbox {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;   
    margin-top:80px;   
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="buttonShow()">CC Open</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonHide()">CC Close</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonStop()">CC Stop</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonPlay()">CC Play</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonReset()">CC Reset</button>

<body onLoad="changer()" id="text">   
  
<div id="transbox"></div>

<p id="Text1"></p>
<p id="Text2"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward

- Store the id of the timer in order to stop it
- Set the index `i` back to 0 for a reset.
- Resume the timer without resetting `i` to resume.
- BONUS: Do not user string evaluation (`"changer()"`) pass a reference to the function instead.

```js
var texter = new Array
texter[0]='good day';
texter[1]='How can I be stopped and started ?';
texter[2]='';
texter[3]='everything should start again from the beginning with the reset button.';
texter[4]='that would be great !!!';
texter[5]='Many thanks for the help';
texter[6]='';
texter[7]='Ciao';
var i=0;
var timerId;

function changer(){
  document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML=texter[i];
  i++;
  if(i==texter.length-1) i = 0;
}

var info = document.getElementById("transbox");
    info.style.display = "none"; 
 
// Infobox display
function buttonShow() {  
    info.style.display = "";
}
// Infobox hidden
function buttonHide() {  
    info.style.display = "none";
}
function buttonStop() {  
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
function buttonPlay() {  
    timerId = window.setInterval ( changer, 2500 ); 
}
function buttonReset() { 
    i = 0;
    changer();
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

```css
#transbox {
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    color:black;
    text-align:center;   
    margin-top:80px;   
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="buttonShow()">CC Open</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonHide()">CC Close</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonStop()">CC Stop</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonPlay()">CC Play</button>
<button type="button" onclick="buttonReset()">CC Reset</button>

<body onLoad="changer()" id="text">   
  
<div id="transbox"></div>

<p id="Text1"></p>
<p id="Text2"></p>
```

Comment: ***@Jamiec*** Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: ***@Jamiec*** I still have a little problem. If `reset` is pressed, the text should not start until `play` is pressed. Now he starts running immediately. I've tried a lot, but it does not really work. Do you have a tip for that?

Comment: @JaDoLo Looking at the code in `buttonStop` and the code in `buttonReset` can you *really* not work that small detail out for yourself? Hint: Combine the stop code into the reset function.

Comment: ***@Jamiec*** I also thought that would have to work, but it does not lead to the desired goal. In both cases, only the text stops, but does not come back to the first sentence.

Comment: @JaDoLo check now

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the ID of the timer:

```
var timer;
function start() {
    stop();
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        document.getElementById('transbox').innerHTML=texter[i];
        i++;
        if (i>=7) i=0;
    }, 2500);
}

function stop() {
    if (timer) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```